# Characterization of ${\rm PSU}(4,2)$ by its order $|{\rm PSU}(4,2)|$ and the number $n_5({\rm PSU}(4,2))$ of its Sylow $5$-subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that $|{\rm PSU}(4,2)|=25920=2^6\cdot3^4\cdot5$, and the number $n_5({\rm PSU}(4,2))$ of Sylow $5$-subgroups of ${\rm PSU}(4,2)$ is $1296=2^4\cdot3^4$.

In Theorem 3.2 of the paper *[Two new characterizations for sporadic simple groups](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4825136_Two_new_characterizations_for_sporadic_simple_groups.)*, Khosravi and Khosravi prove that every sporadic simple group $S$ is uniquely determined by its order $|S|$ and the number of its Sylow $p$-subgroups $n_p(S)$, where $p$ is the largest element of $$\pi(S)=\{p\mid p~{\rm is~a~divisor~of}~|S|\}.$$ I just want to prove the same result for ${\rm PSU}(4,2)$. But I cannot follow the proof of Theorem 3.2. In particular, in the first paragraph of the proof of Theorem 3.2 it says that "**... and so $|G/K|$ is a divisor of $n_p(G)$**". I cannot catch the idea of this sentence. May someone give me a more detailed explanation？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recalling the definition that $n_p(G)=|N_G(P)|$ where $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ we have $$N_G(P)/N_G(K)\cong G/K\implies \left|N_G(P)/N_G(K)\right|=|G/K|$$ and the result follows as $\left|N_G(P)/N_G(K)\right|$ divides $|N_G(P)|$.

Comment: Oh, I see, In paper $n_p(G)=|N_G(P)|$. Thank you very much!